# long integer is wrong after power a large number in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

**When I power (exponentiate) a large number and round the result to long integer it's wrong**. (In my context, I'm calculating RSA public and private keys).

```
from fractions import gcd
def doLoop(e, totient):
    v = 0
    i = 1
    x = 0
    vv = 0
    while vv == 0:
        x = (e * i - 1) % totient
        if x == 0:
            v = i
            vv = 1
        i = i + 1
    return v

primeX = 3
primeY = 11
n = primeX*primeY
totient = (primeX - 1) * (primeY - 1)
e = 17
privatekey = doLoop(e, totient)
m = 9
encryptedvalue = int(int(math.pow(m,e)) % n)
int(math.pow(encryptedvalue,privatekey)) % n


>>> m
9
>>> e
17
>>> n
33
>>> int(math.pow(m,e)) % n
14L
```

should be 15 but 14

long integer is wrong

```
>>> int(round(math.pow(m,e)))
16677181699666568L
```

round number is also wrong

should be

```
16677181699666569
```

[image]

Comment: With the values you specify, I get int(math.pow(m,e)) % n = 16, not 15 or 14.

Comment: The [documentation for `round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) explains this

Comment: it's just a value of 9 power of 17.
then it could be in the for of LONG INT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can confirm... but heres some work arounds..

```
>>> int(math.pow(9,17)) 
16677181699666568 
>>> 9**17 
16677181699666569 
>>> pow(9, 17)
16677181699666569
>>>
```

```
math.pow(x, y)
Return x raised to the power y. Exceptional cases follow Annex ‘F’ of the C99 standard as far as possible. In particular, pow(1.0, x) and pow(x, 0.0) always return 1.0, even when x is a zero or a NaN. If both x and y are finite, x is negative, and y is not an integer then pow(x, y) is undefined, and raises ValueError.

Unlike the built-in ** operator, math.pow() converts both its arguments to type float. Use ** or the built-in pow() function for computing exact integer powers.

Changed in version 2.6: The outcome of 1**nan and nan**0 was undefined.
```